# How to send otp code sms in firebase with java android?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a Android Studio project with firebase, I already implement firebase correctly.

im trying to make a sign in with sms authentication, everything works but no sms arrives[image]

I already configure firebase authentication

here's some code

```
mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verification Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verification Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                       PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Code Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
```

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.bt_send_otp:

                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        etPhone.getText().toString(),        // Phone number to verify
                        1,                 // Timeout duration
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES,   // Unit of timeout
                        this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                        mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

                break;
            case R.id.bt_resend_otp:
                break;
            case R.id.bt_verify_otp:
                break;
        }
   }
```

when I press the send otp button the toast "Code Sent" appears

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a test number, `OTP` will not arrive. Though for testing you can use the verification code you added with the test phone number on the console.
`Firebase Console Dashboard` -> `Authentication` -> `SignIn Method` -> `Phone` -> `Phone numbers for testing`.

[image]

Check out the docs for `Firebase Phone Verification` for `Android` : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=1#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers

Comment: Thank u so much, it works. I have a question, is there some configuration to send the OTP to a number that is not In testing? Because if I put a different number it goes to "verification failed"

Comment: No, you can so that only when the app is in production. For debugging you will, unfortunately, need to add the test phone yourself.